# Uploading a picture with a imagebox Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, file-upload, bots

Good evening,

I am currently working on a automated bot that uploads ebay ad's (if you want to call it like that).

I am currently struggling to upload a picture.

[image]

This is how it looks like and when you press on the camera you need to go through your files and select the picture.

**My question:**

How can i insert the Picture with python selenium.

**Background**

If someone wants to take a deeper dive on the html what ever, here is the link to the Website i am trying to bot:

Ebay-kleinanzeigen.de

You need to create an account and press on "create an ad" or something simmilar to this.

It should look something like this:
[image]

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most easy and widely used way to upload a file with Selenium is not to click the "upload" button you see as a user rather to send that file directly to some specific element on the page. In most cases it will be element located by this XPath: `//input[@type='file']`. So if your file location on your PC is something like
`path = "C://folder/filename.extension"` you can simply upload it with the following command:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").send_keys(path)
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for the quick reply. 

I added the code that you posted, but it doesn't work for me. I am getting the error message: "ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable". I copied the whole XPath of the clickable HTML element.

Comment: What element are you trying to click? I mentioned to use `send_keys` method only here.

Comment: Excuse me, I am not trying to click it. I am trying to use the send_keys Method on the element that you usually click on. so I copied the XPath from the little camera Box, that  you can see on the first Picture of my Post.

Comment: And this is not what I told you to do... You should send the actual path to your file on the disk to this element `//input[@type='file']`, not to the element you are clicking as a user. `//input[@type='file']` is a special element, it is not visible to users, but this is the element you can use with Selenium.

Comment: Yea I did this before and as a result, it clicked the send key. The whole thing got published without the picture.

Comment: Wait forget what I said, it gets Uploaded, but somehow it stops after 0.5 sec.

Comment: So, if it gets uploaded - this is exactly what it should do. What happens after that - I have no idea, you didn't share your code.... Also, in case it uploads, I think we should mark this question as resolved and in case of additional issues we should open a new question...

Comment: Sure, I am already on it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: It's OKay, you are always welcome!